# Cakephp: Admin Login as User onClick

Tags: cakephp

i am looking for a way how i (logged in as Administrator) can log me in as a specific user (that i select from a list of users, list is already present) onclick without knowing it's password?

All users have different passwords, so equal passwords are not an option.

**OK, Question closed. Here is the solution:**

P.S. group with id 2 is my Admin Group.

```
function loginasuser($user_id = null) {

    if (!$user_id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid User.', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    $data = $this->Auth->user();

    if($data['User']['group_id'] == 2 || $_SESSION['Auth']['Admin']['id']==$user_id) {

    $user_data = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $user_id)));

    if ($user_data['User']['group_id']==2 && $user_data['User']['id']<>$_SESSION['Auth']['Admin']['id']) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('You can only log in as user', true));
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('/users'));
    }

        $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id']=$user_data['User']['id'];
    $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['username']=$user_data['User']['username'];
    $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['group_id']=$user_data['User']['group_id'];
    $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['client_id']=$user_data['User']['client_id'];
    $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['created']=$user_data['User']['created'];
    $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['modified']=$user_data['User']['modified'];
    $_SESSION['Auth']['Admin']['id']=$data['User']['id'];

        if($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['group_id']==2) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('/ADMINHOME'));
        }
        else {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('/USERSHOME'));
        }
    }
    else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Only admins are alowed to do so!', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }

}
```

And to go back as admin, you could do:

```
<? if($_SESSION['Auth']['Admin']['id']>0) { ?>
<a href="/loginasuser/<?=$_SESSION['Auth']['Admin']['id'];?>">Go Back as Admin</a><? }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "username" (email Id) to create session.

On Onclick , trigger an Ajax call, pass the username and set the session using that username. 
(Just trigger this call when admin change the selection box, `onChange(this.value)`)

Then just redirect user to end user home page. Put a link to come back to admin dashboard. This helps admin can login as other user.

(Use different session namespace for admin and end user)

$_SESSION['user'] for end user and $_SESSIION['admin'] for admin user.

Comment: thanks, that pointed me to the right direktion. i will post my complete function in case someone needs it.